# Getting "vector subscript out of range" error. Unsure where access violation occurs

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on an assignment for one of my CS courses. My professor wants us to implement a certain data structure using an array. I've been reviewing my code to see where I may be accessing outside of the vector's range, but I'm not seeing anything that I think is wrong.

When I run the test .cpp file, it only extracts one item before breaking.

Could someone point out any glaring mistakes in my code?

```
class minHeap {
private:
vector<int> nodes;
int current;

int parent(int i) {
    return (i-1)/2;
}

int leftChild(int i) {
    return 2*i+1;
}

int rightChild(int i) {
    return 2*i+2;
}

void bubbleUp(int i) {
    if(i > 0) {
        int p = parent(i);
        if(nodes[i] < nodes[p]) {
            swap(nodes[i], nodes[p]);
            bubbleUp(p);
        }
    }
}

void bubbleDown(int i) {
    if(i < current) {
        int a = leftChild(i);
        int b = rightChild(i);

        if(a <= current) {
            if(nodes[i] > nodes[a] || nodes[i] > nodes[b]) {
                if(nodes[a] < nodes[b]) {
                    swap(nodes[i], nodes[a]);
                    bubbleDown(a);
                }
                else {
                    swap(nodes[i], nodes[b]);
                    bubbleDown(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public:
minHeap() {
    current = -1;
}

void insert(int x) {
    current++;
    nodes.push_back(x);
    bubbleUp(current);
}

int extractMin() {
    int min = nodes[0];
    swap(nodes[0], nodes[current]);
    current--;
    nodes.pop_back();
    bubbleDown(0);
    return min;
}

bool empty() {
    if(current < 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
};
```

Comment: extractMin returns the minimum before the swap. It that what you intend?

Comment: @Bathsheba It isn't. It should swap, decrement my counter, remove the last item (which should now be the min), call bubbleDown, then return the min. I don't see how it returns prior to that though. It's the last thing happening.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger and seeing what line the problem occurs on?  As a side note, you do not need all the empty else clauses and you should change things like `if(i <= 0) {} else {...}` to `if(i > 0) { what used to be in the else }`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja In the test program given by my prof, it breaks on the second call of extractMin. I've been  following my methods on paper but still don't see the problem. The error says "vector subscript out of range", line 932. I'm guessing line 932 is in the code for the vector class. And I'll clean up the cases, it's just like that from how I was thinking of the problem.

Comment: There is a goot strategy that helps with such errors: Document your assumptions. For example, `extractMin()` assumes that there are at least `current + 1` elements (to allow indices `0` and `current`). Therefore, just add `assert(nodes.size() >= current + 1);` to that function. It will then tell you loudly when this precondition is violated.

Answer (score 1):

Update code

```
int parent(int i) {
    int res = (i-1)/2;
    if (!(res >= 0 && res <= current)) cout << "error: parent(" << i << ") out of index";
    return res;
}

int leftChild(int i) {
    int res = 2*i+1;
    if (!(res >= 0 && res <= current)) cout << "error: leftChild(" << i << ") out of index";
    return res;
}

int rightChild(int i) {
    int res = 2*i+2;
    if (!(res >= 0 && res <= current)) cout << "error: rightChild(" << i << ") out of index";
    return res;
}
```

And you will see

```
error: rightChild(0) out of index1
```

when extracting min from heap of size 3. You need to take into account right child index in

```
if(a > current) {}
else {
    if(nodes[i] > nodes[a] || nodes[i] > nodes[b]) {
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. You pointing out that I didn't consider if the right child was out of range helped me come up some better cases. I got the class working properly.